# Unexpected growth Transaction log file 100 GB which is part of Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, transactional-replication

I configured transactional replication on SQL Server 2014/Windows Server 2012. The database size is only 30 MB, but log file size is 100 GB. Every day, the log file size is growing 5-7 GB.

Database transaction log file size increased abnormally. Data file size is 30MB and the transaction log file grows to 95 GB.

While database under testing mode...

Subscriber of replication is also primary replica of Always On Availability Group.

How to reduce the size of transaction log file?

I had taken log backup and in full recovery model.

```
SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;
```

...returns `LOG_BACKUP`.

Replication is running successfully. Subscriber is receiving changes from publisher.

Comment: Please can you post the output of sp_replcounters  on the publisher, thanks.

Comment: You do backup regularly?

Comment: You said you took one log backup. In full recovery, you need lots of log backups. https://www.scarydba.com/2011/01/18/dba-101-why-is-my-log-file-full/

Answer (score 0):

You may run below scripts to check the log reuse wait of the database(s):

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS db_name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;
```